# Django redirect() not working

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

**The Ideal:** User submits a form with data for `Entry A` at URL `/entry/1` and is then taken to the same form but for `Entry B` at URL `/entry/2` - at the moment the form submits to the same view and I'm attempting to redirect to the next entry.

**The Problem:** Redirection simply doesn't work, my view function is defined as:

```
def editor(request, entry_id):
```

Within the view I handle post data and have used the following lines to attempt redirection:

- `redirect('myapp.views.editor', entry_id=next_id)`
- `redirect('myapp.views.editor', kwargs={ 'entry_id': next_id })`
- `redirect('/entry/{0}'.format(next_id))`
- `HttpResponseRedirect('/entry/{0}'.format(next_id))`

**What I Know:**

- The `redirect` shortcut works in other views
- The `next_id` is correct and definitely has a value
- The code is technically valid - **this fails silently**
- Attempting to redirect to a different view doesn't work either

Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Comment: Maybe you've missed `return` statement? I.e `return HttpResponseRedirect('/entry/{0}'.format(next_id))`

Comment: @stalk I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for pointing that out! If you'd like to add it as an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've just missed `return` statement. So, add it:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/entry/{0}'.format(next_id))
```

Comment: As an added point, this "return" works for all attempts shown in the question.